# Diffie-Hellman computing public key with a large private key

Tags: diffie-hellman

Given is Generator $g = 5$, Multiplicative group $F_{10007}^*$, Private key = 7347.

Then public key is $5^{7347} \bmod 10007$ right?

On a calculator this gives an overflow error, how am I supposed to calculate the public key when a private key is a large number?

Comment: In addition to using numerous existing programs, you could [look at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On a calculator this gives overflow error, how am I supposed to calculate the public key when a private key is a large number?

A standard calculator cannot handle that, and we don't expect it. If you have a programmable one you can use square-and-multiply as in [levgeni's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89038/18298). This, however, will fail when the calculator cannot handle integers (the modulus) larger than the calculator's word size.

There are better and easy approaches

1. Use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%205%5E7347%20mod%2010007%20) `5^7347 mod 10007`
2. Use [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) `5^7347 % 10007`
3. Use Python's `pow` that takes a third parameters as modulus `pow(5,7347,10007)` and uses modular-square-and-multiply. [Online](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea I could calculate this using Wolfram.

Comment: Wolfram can do a lot of things online. You can think that they carry their system to online.  SageMath, on the other hand, is free and uses Python 3 syntax. It worth learning. Of course, I did not count the other languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux/mac you can also use [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)):

```
echo "(5^7347)%10007" | bc
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that any particular implementation of `bc` won't overflow available memory.

Answer (score 1):

5^{7347} is a huge integer (with thousands bits), if you are using standard integer encoding, you can only use few hundreds bits ($128$, in general).

But, if you are looking the fact that you don't need to compute entirely this integer, you can use the square-and-multiply algorithm smartly :

```
pow (a,b) : if b is odd then return (a* (pow (a, b-1)) mod 10007)
        elif b == 0 then return 1
        elif return (pow ((a*a) mod 10007, b/2)
```

By using modulo 10007 at each step, you can be sure that your integers will be never too big.